# JEST throws .finally is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

Here is my react component:

```
import { sendAnalytics } from 'analytics';

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    myMethod() {
        console.log('do something!');
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Button 
                onClick={submitAnalytics({name: 'foo'}).finally(this.myMethod())} 
                dataset={{"data-id": "button"}}
            > Send Analytics
            </Button>
            }
        )
    }
}
```

And my test is like so:

```
import * as analytics from 'analytics';
jest.mock('analytics');

describe('Analytics', () => {
    it('Should call analytics when button is clicked', () => {
        analytics.submitAnalytics.mockResolvedValue(Promise.resolve(true));
        const tree = ReactTestRenderer.create(<MyComponent />);

        // Actual implementation of following 3 lines is slightly different.
        const button = tree.root.findByProps({"data-id": "button"});
        button.props.onClick();
        expect(analytics.submitAnalytics).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

I tried several different mocking strategies like:

```
analytics.submitAnalytics.mockImplementation(() => {
    return Promise.resolve(true)
});
```

Nothing seems to work out. I keep getting the following error:

`TypeError: (0 , analytics.submitAnalytics)(...).finally is not a function`.

I don't know why. Any help appreciated.
Please let me know if you need any more contextual code.

Comment: Have you tried returning a new Promise instead of returning the result of the resolve method?

Comment: Yes I did that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out folks! Here's what was to be done:

```
analytics.submitPayload = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
  return {
    finally: () => {
      return true;
    }
  };
});
```

I don't know if this is right or wrong, but it works. Please let me know if there's a better way to do it.

Answer (score 7):

Importing `@babel/polyfill` before the test also solve this problem

```
import '@babel/polyfill';

// Your tests...
```

Answer (score 3):

Upgrading my node version from

`v8.10.0`

to

`v10.19.0`

Resolved this error.

Looking at the Browser Compatibility chart on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/finally) it looks like .finally() is not supported in Node until `10.0.0`

Answer (score 2):

`import '@babel/polyfill';` worked for me, but is deprecated since babel 7.4.

Instead, import this works fine as well:

```
import "core-js/stable";
import "regenerator-runtime/runtime";
```

eventually, I just updated node version (from 8.10.2 to 12.16.1)

Answer (score 0):

I faced same challenge.
Reason-  Jest runs in Node enviroment,and "**Finally**" is supported from Node version- **10.0.0.** But my Jenkins versions was 8.x so As a quick fix you can remove finally from code. Later we can upgrade local and remote server version.

Below is MDN link-
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/finally
[image: finally supports (MDN)]